# The system of equations

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-system

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ that $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}=1$. We want to find $x,y,z,w$ in the following equations:

$$\begin{align}
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}&=1 \tag{1}\\
x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}-w^{2}&=a \tag{2}\\
xw+yz&=2b \tag{3}\\
yw-xz&=2c.\tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to find $w$?

Answer (score 1):

First, let $\gamma=z^2+w^2$. Now note that
\begin{align}
a^2+2(2b)^2+2(2c)^2&=(x^2+y^2)^2+\gamma^2\\
&=(a+\gamma)^2+\gamma^2\\
8b^2+8c^2&=2a\gamma+2\gamma^2\\
16b^2+16c^2&=4a\gamma+4\gamma^2
\end{align}
Now note that $2\gamma=1-a$ and $b^2+c^2=1-a^2$, so that this rewrites to
$$16-16a^2=2a(1-a)+(1-a)^2$$
which we can solve for $a$, obtaining $a=1$ or $a=-1$. In both cases, $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ rewrites to $b^2+c^2=0$, and since squares are non-negative, we can conclude that $b=c=0$.

---

So we need to solve (for $a=1$ and $a=-1$):
\begin{align}
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}&=1\\
x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}-w^{2}&=a\\
xw+yz&=0\\
yw-xz&=0
\end{align}

---

**Case one: $a=1$**

We immediately see that $1-a=z^2+w^2=0$, so that $z=w=0$. We are left with $x^2+y^2=0$, and see that the general solution is given by
$$(x,y,z,w)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0,0)$$
for any real $\theta$.

---

**Case two: $a=-1$**

From this, we see $a+1=x^2+y^2=0$, and so $x=y=0$; and we are left with $z^2+w^2=1$. Now the general solution becomes

$$(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$$
for any real theta.

---

Therefore,

> All solutions are given by, for any $\theta\in\Bbb R$:
>   $$(x,y,z,w)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0,0)$$ or $$(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$$

Comment: In my new post, this problem is without condition for $a,b,c$. See that, please.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (assuming $x,y,z,w$ are reals): let $u=y+ix$ and $v=w+iz$ then the system becomes:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
|u|^2+|v|^2 &= 1 \\
|u|^2-|v|^2 &= a \\
uv & = 2c + 2bi 
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

From the first 2 equations $|u|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1+a)\,$, $|v|^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-a)\,$, so $|uv|^2 =\frac{1}{4}(1-a^2)=\frac{1}{4}(b^2+c^2)$. From the third equation $|uv|^2=4(c^2+b^2)\,$, and equating the two gives $b=c=0 \implies uv=0$. The rest should be straightforward to fill in.