# The system of equation 2

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-system

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$. We want to find $x,y,z,w$ in the following equations(according to $a,b,c$):

$$\begin{align}
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+w^{2}&=1 \tag{1}\\
x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}-w^{2}&=a \tag{2}\\
xw+yz&=2b \tag{3}\\
yw-xz&=2c.\tag{4}
\end{align}$$

(In my other [**post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210463/the-system-of-equations), that problem had a condition. But in this post, there is not.)

Answer (score 1):

Using complex numbers, let $p:=x+iy$, and $q:=w+iz$.

From the first two equations, you can easily derive the values of $|p|$ and $|q|$ (as $\sqrt{(1\pm a)/2}$).
The last two equations can be combined as $$pq^*=2(b+ic).$$

Then you can obtain the phase shift between $p$ and $q$ (which is the argument of $b+ic$) and their moduli, but the absolute phases remain undetermined.

In addition, the compatibility condition $$\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}2=2\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$$ must be fulfilled.